# Why does an address saved in an array change from 6 to 7 bytes?

Tags: c, pointers, x86-64, memory-address

I'm writing a program for storage management, which operates with pointers on dynamic memory.

To do so, I used a struct (Zone) which handles and manages each block of allocated memory, storing 2 arrays of void*, one for the starting addresses of certain memory blocks and the other for the ending addresses.

To retrieve a block from a given pointer whose address is in the boundaries of the block, a function scans the Zones and their starting/ending addresses and checks if the pointer is contained in a pair of such addresses (meaning the pointer "points" at that block).

```
int retrieve_block(void* ptr, Zone* head, void** start, void** end){
    int i;
    void** s;
    void** e;

    Zone* curr = head;
    while(curr != NULL){
        s = curr->starting_addr;
        e = curr->ending_addr;
        for(i=0; i<MAX_BLOCKS; i++){
            if(s[i] == NULL){
                break;
            }

            if(s[i]<=ptr && ptr<=e[i]){
                *start = s[i];
                *end = e[i];

                return i;
            }
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

During the check `(s[i]<=ptr && ptr<=e[i])` I notices that, just for one value of s[i], the address which the program finds in it is something like **0x55b068d1f2caca**, while it should have been (and was previously stored inside it) **0x55b068d1f2ca**.

The result is that the program does not recognize the pointer passed to the function as being inside the block.

Why does this happen? Why does the last byte repeat itself changing the address?

Comment: Impossible to say with just an incomplete code snippet. Please provide a complete [mre]. Also include the exact input, expected result and actual result. Please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: Also, how are you determining the values of `s[i]`? Include  that as part of the MRE.

Comment: `0x55b068d1f2caca` isn't a canonical (48-bit sign-extended) address for x86-64.  The upper 16 bits don't match bit #47.  So it definitely can't be the address where something was found (unless you're running on an Ice Lake system with PML5 for 57-bit virtual addresses, but the leading `0x55` is likely the top of a 48-bit address, i.e. near the middle of the user-space range.)  So if this isn't just something getting printed wrong with an extra `ca` left over on your terminal, something in your program is corrupting something, like left-shifting and appended a copy of the low 8 bits.

Comment: Based on what you're doing with void pointers, my guess is that somewhere, somehow, you add 1 and assign a pointer misaligned.

Comment: stark probably has the right idea.  Check for compiler warnings re: doing pointer math on `void*`; some compilers (I think GCC) allow `ptr + 1` for `void*` to work the same as for `char*`.  So perhaps you offset a `void*` then cast it to `void**` to deref and assign something?  Use `-Wall`, and if that doesn't help use `gcc -Og -fsanitize=undefined` to add some runtime checks.

Comment: thanks so much @stark and @Peter it was the bad alignment. `gcc -Og -fsanitize=undefined` helped a lot!